# Detect mouseup on particular div jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two divs : 1 div with draggable/droppable elements and 1 div which reveices the elements.
I'd like to open a popup and an element is dragged into the second div.
Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="elements">
  <div class="drag">
  </div>
  <div class="drag">
  </div>
  <div class="drag">
  </div>
  <div class="drag">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">

</div>

$('.drag').draggable().resizable();

$('.drag').mouseup(function(e) {
  var zone = $(".container");
  var target = $(e.target);
  if (target.is(zone)){
    alert("test");   
  }    
});
```

And [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1w34vck6/)

I'm not able to detect the zone actually. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like @Ronen Suggested you should read the documentation, You should have a droppable event instead of mouseup:

```
$('.drag').draggable().resizable();
$( ".container" ).droppable({
      classes: {
        "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
      },
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        alert("test"); 
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like this:

```
$('.drag').draggable().resizable();
$( ".container" ).droppable({
  accept: ".drag",
  classes: {
    "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-default"
  },
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
   alert("test"); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry bro, you deserve upvotes more than I do, you posted your answer seconds before mine, +1 for that

Comment: Thanks both of you !